# `particle` does not live long enough & cannot move out of `particle` because it is borrowed

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, ownership

I don't yet fully understand the concepts of Ownership, Borrowing, and Lifetimes in Rust and this is pretty confusing.

Basically, I get these two errors when I compile:

```
error[E0597]: `particle` does not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:80:20
   |
78 |     let mut particle = Particle::new(Vector3::ZERO, 20.0, 0.95);
   |         ------------ binding `particle` declared here
79 |
80 |     simulation.add(&mut particle);
   |     ---------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^-
   |     |              |
   |     |              borrowed value does not live long enough
   |     argument requires that `particle` is borrowed for `'static`
...
97 | }
   | - `particle` dropped here while still borrowed
```

```
error\[E0505\]: cannot move out of `particle` because it is borrowed
\--\> src\\main.rs:82:24
|
78 |     let mut particle = Particle::new(Vector3::ZERO, 20.0, 0.95);
|         ------------ binding `particle` declared here
79 |
80 |     simulation.add(&mut particle);
|     -----------------------------
|     |              |
|     |              borrow of `particle` occurs here
|     argument requires that `particle` is borrowed for `'static`
81 |
82 |     window.render_loop(move |mut frame_input| {
|                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move out of `particle` occurs here
...
86 |         particle.apply_force(Vector3 { x: 0.0, y: -G, z: 0.0 } \* particle.mass);
|         -------- move occurs due to use in closure
```

And here's all the relevant code:

```rs
// main.rs

let window = Window::new(WindowSettings {
    title: String::from("test"),
    max_size: Some((1600, 900)),

    ..Default::default()
}).unwrap();

let mut particle = Particle::new(Vector3::ZERO, 20.0, 0.95);
let mut simulation = ParticleSimulation::new();

simulation.add(&mut particle);

window.render_loop(move |mut frame_input| {
    particle.apply_force(Vector3 { x: 0.0, y: -G, z: 0.0 } * particle.mass);
    simulation.update(0.001 * frame_input.elapsed_time);

    FrameOutput::default()
});
```

```rs
// particle.rs

pub struct Particle {
    pub position: Vector3,

    velocity: Vector3,
    force: Vector3,

    damping: f64,
    pub mass: f64,
    pub inverse_mass: f64
}

impl Particle {
    pub fn new(position: Vector3, mass: f64, damping: f64) -> Particle {
        Particle {
            position,

            velocity: Vector3::ZERO,
            force: Vector3::ZERO,

            damping,
            mass,
            inverse_mass: 1.0 / mass,
        }
    }

    pub fn apply_force(&mut self, force: Vector3) {
        self.force += force;
    }

    pub fn update(&mut self, delta_time: f64) {
        assert!(delta_time >= 0.0, "negative delta_time");

        self.position += self.velocity * delta_time;

        let acceleration = self.force * self.inverse_mass;

        self.velocity += acceleration * delta_time;
        self.velocity *= self.damping.powf(delta_time);

        self.force = Vector3::ZERO;
    }
}

pub struct ParticleSimulation<'a> {
    particles: Vec<&'a mut Particle>,
}

impl<'a> ParticleSimulation<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        ParticleSimulation {
            particles: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn add(&mut self, particle: &'a mut Particle) {
        self.particles.push(particle)
    }

    pub fn update(&mut self, delta_time: f64) {
        for particle in self.particles.iter_mut() {
            particle.update(delta_time);
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing an extra step or am I doing something wrong?

I haven't tried anything yet, and all I am expecting is for this to compile and run.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], particularly, please remove or replace `Vector3`, `window`, `camera`, `controls`, `G`, `sphere`, `sun`, `Particle`, `Mat4`, `ClearState`, `FrameOutput` (in order of [the compilers complaints](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=14134f8fec3d673d1c2e7b2ea969dfe3)) with defined things (or if you can't, then tell us which library you import them from) and don't pull them out of thin air.

Comment: Vector3 and Particle I made myself, G is just a constant I defined. I removed the rest of the code which seemed unnecessary. Also I am using a library called three_d to render stuff.

Comment: The code still produces a different error than you claim.